# How to delete all files and subdirectories in Bash including edge cases

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to delete all files and subdirectories from a given directory in Bash where I am the owner of the directory (which is writable) and everything underneath.  I do not have root access.  I would like an answer that keeps in mind at very least the following scenario:

```
mkdir foo
touch foo/bar
chmod 555 foo
```

as well as any other edge cases.  My current solution is

```
chmod -R 777 * &> /dev/null    # ignore error when pwd is already empty
rm -rf *
```

Are there other edge cases I haven't thought of and how would I deal with them?  Is there a more robust or simpler answer?

Comment: You should not ignore errors of `chmod`

Comment: What other errors could there be (I own everything)?  Bash does offer fine control over exception handling.

Comment: Why do you need the chmod?

Comment: Did you try the scenario I provided?  You get `rm: cannot remove ‘foo/bar’: Permission denied`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally feel more comfortably with using `find`.  Unfortunately, you'll ned two passes in your example.  (Or, at least, I wasn't able to write a single-pass command.)

```
find . -execdir chmod 0700 '{}' ';'
find . -delete
```

This will handle empty directories and hidden files gracefully.

Note that I only set the permission bits to 0700 (not 0777).  This is more than enough for deleting the files and does not open up (that many) security holes.  If you are concerned, you should actually rather do

```
find . '(' -type d -execdir chmod 0700 '{}' ';' ')' -or -execdir chmod 0600 '{}' ';'
```

to only set the executable bit on directories.

However you do it, this approach will not be immune to race conditions if the directory tree is modified concurrently.

Note that `-execdir` is a GNU extension.  If you need strict POSIX compliance, you'll need to go with the less safe `-exec`.

Answer (score 0):

The main edge case I see is if there are very many names in the current directory.  That could lead to `*` expanding to so many names that it exceeds the maximum length of a command line.  To avoid this, simply use `.` instead of `*`; this will also catch hidden files (those starting with `.`).

Comment: Good point, but I get `rm: cannot remove directory: ‘.’` when I try that `rm -rf .`